# 32-bit bitwise Exclusive-OR negation value of a binary packet

Tags: c++, c, binary, erlang

I am required to generate a 4 byte checksum which is defined as "a 32-bit bitwise exclusive-OR negation value" of some piece of binary data. I am re-writing the encode/decode sections of a certain MML interface for a billing system in Erlang.

The C/C++ version of such a function is here below:

```
Function: GetChkSum 
Description: 
A 32-bit bitwise Exclusive-OR negation value of "message header 
+ session header + transaction header + operation information". 
Input: 
len indicates the total length of "message header + session header 
+ transaction header + operation information". 
Buf indicates the string consisting of message header, session header, 
transaction header, and operation information. 
Output: res indicates the result of the 32-bit bitwise Exclusive-OR negation 
value


void GetChkSum(Int len, PSTR buf, PSTR res) 
{ 
  memset(res, 0, MSG_CHKSUM_LEN); 
  for(int i=0; i<len; i+=4) 
  { 
    res[0]^=(buf+i)[0]; 
    res[1]^=(buf+i)[1]; 
    res[2]^=(buf+i)[2]; 
    res[3]^=(buf+i)[3]; 
  }; 
  res[0]=~res[0]; 
  res[1]=~res[1]; 
  res[2]=~res[2]; 
  res[3]=~res[3]; 
};
```

I am required to re-write this in Erlang. How can I do this?

Comment: could someone please provide a comment as an explanation for the down vote ?

Comment: You did not ask a question. (Questions typically end with a ***?***)  You told us your Erlang requirements, and posted some C code.  Do you expect us to write your code for you?  More typically on this site, people encounter difficulties, and ask *specific questions* so that we can respond with *specific answers*.

Comment: Okay, cool. I have done some edits. I am hoping that a fellow out there could assist show me how to do a bitwise `xor` negation in erlang

Comment: I took the liberty to do a rollback to the C++ code, as it is highly relevant to the question.

Comment: If I google "xor erlang" and "binary not erlang", I get some pretty darn good results, *(and I don't even know the first thing about erlang!!)*   What are you really having difficulties with??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no difficulty to do an xor in erlang (the operator to use is bxor and works with integer). But to write any code you need to define the "format" of input and output first. From your example I guess it may be ascii code, stored in a binary, or a string??

Once you have define the input type, the result can be evaluated with a function of the type:

```
negxor(<<>>,R) -> int_to_your_result_type(bnot(R) band 16#FFFFFFFF);
negxor(<<H:32,Q:binary>>,R) -> negxor(Q,R bxor H).
```

and you can call it with `negxor(your_input_to_binary(Input),0)`.